# Low Level binding in javafx(using computeValue)

Tags: java, javafx

I am beginner in javafx.
I want to bind a vertical slider to a rectangle height.
I want to use low level binding.But it doesn't do anything.
Please help me . Thank's

```
   rect = (Rectangle) root.lookup("#rect");
   vSlider = (Slider) root.lookup("#vSlider");
     final RectangleProperty rectangle = new RectangleProperty(rect);

   DoubleBinding vSliderBind = new DoubleBinding() {
         {
             super.bind(vSlider.valueProperty(),rectangle.heightpProperty());
         }

        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            rectangle.setHeightp(vSlider.valueProperty().doubleValue()*3);
           // System.out.print("vslider");
            return rectangle.getHeightp() ;
        }
    };
   vSliderBind.get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to use low level binding for this? The essence of the low level binding (as you say it) is to perform complex calculations, that are not possible with the fluent API. For binding `height` to the `value` of the slider, a simple line is sufficient:

```
r.heightProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
```

Even if you wanted simple manipulations (e.g. multiply it by something, be it a constant *or another property*):

```
r.heightProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().multiply(0.5));
```

The following is a full code listing that will do the job:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RectHeightSlider extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(10);
        slider.setMax(100);
        slider.setValue(50);
        slider.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        root.getChildren().add(slider);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setWidth(100);
        r.heightProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
        root.getChildren().add(r);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(r, 0.0);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you *have* to do it low-level then do something like:

```
DoubleBinding vSliderBind = new DoubleBinding() {
    {
        super.bind(vSlider.valueProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        return vSlider.getValue();
    }
};

rectangle.heightProperty().bind(vSliderBind);
```

The reasoning is:

- with `super.bind()` you set listeners to the properties from which the binding depends. This binding *depends* on the value of the slider and *computes* the height of the rectangle; thus you have to `bind()` it only to the value of the slider.
- with `computeValue()` you do as it says: compute the actual output value (here: the height of the rect) whenever one or more of the bound properties change. Here the computation is a simple identity ( f(x)=x ), in other cases it may be more complex.

Another way to do it is adding a listener to the value property, then manually update the height.

Comment: I should do it.Because this is my homework ! But Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there any other way for do it ?

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. I added what you want, but it is so trivial that I am thinkning is this really it?

Comment: Oh.Thank you so much...Yes, it work perfectly and I understood this kind of binding very good.Thank you again.